# How do I change the type of a string to a bytestring?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have `'\x87'` and I want `b'\x87'`.
I know, that there exists `.encode()`, but when I execute `('\x87').encode()`, I get `b'\xc2\x87'` and not `b'\x87'`.
Is there any way to tell python that it should interpret the given string as a bytestring without possibly changing it in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
my_str = '\x87'
my_str_as_bytes = my_str.encode(encoding='latin')
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

```py
bytes(ord(x) for x in '\x87')
```